# NoSuchMethodException: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.scala when running pyspark code zepplin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run a pyspark cell in zeppelin but i get a NoSuchMethodException on scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.scala

cell code:

```
%pyspark

print("hello")
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$loopPostInit()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.callMethod(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:268)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.callMethod(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:262)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkScala211Interpreter.open(SparkScala211Interpreter.scala:84)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.NewSparkInterpreter.open(NewSparkInterpreter.java:102)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.getSparkInterpreter(PySparkInterpreter.java:664)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.createGatewayServerAndStartScript(PySparkInterpreter.java:260)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.open(PySparkInterpreter.java:194)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:617)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

zeppelin version: 0.8.0

spark version: 2.4.0

scala version: 2.11.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is described in [[ZEPPELIN-3810] Support Spark 2.4](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/3206) and release of zeppelin 0.8.1 has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is something about spark version with zeppelin, I had the same error, I just tried to change spark version to 2.3.2 and work it.